# A upload file is 0byte on django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

My webserver symbolic linked another server. But a uploaded file was 0 byte when I uploaded file. It was work well before (I used just web server directory)

I don't have any idea dealing with this problem. Does anybody have a trouble like this problem on NFS?

In addition, It works well if I use on Python console.

Thanks,

Comment: You have provided no information that anybody could use to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem. It was django problem with NFS.

If you have same trouble, check this URLs.

- http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg55892.html
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9400